# Eclipse export libraries into jar

Tags: java, eclipse

So my old jar has the libraries exported into it as folders containing the .class files. And my new jar has each library .jar packaged into my jar in a libs folder like my workspace. I need it to export with the former setup. Pictures below explain my issue further.

The reason the packaging changed is because I reinstalled my OS and I don't remember how I had done it before since it's been a while since I last exported a jar for this project, I think what I did last time to get around this issue was I used IntelliJ Idea to export it but I'd much prefer figure this out with Eclipse. There seems to be a setting that does exactly what I want under the Runnable Jar Export wizard but I'm not exporting a runnable jar as it doesn't have a Main method.

old jar picture:

[image: pic 1]

new jar picture:

[image: pic 2]

new jar picture 2:

[image: pic 3]

[image: gif]

Comment: The second one looks like you have used the _Archive File_ export wizard by mistake. Please tell exactly what you have done in which version of Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger I added my process to the original post

Comment: I see. Yes, this is a feature only of the _Runnable JAR file_, not of the _JAR file_ export wizard. If you do not want to create a dummy main method, you have to use Ant, Maven, Gradle or something else to create a fat JAR.

Comment: @howlger The dummy main was a good idea, which packaged it how I wanted but then it wouldn't include the plugin.yml which is necessary for the application. So I ended up trying IntelliJ Idea again which does what I needed out of the box. Thanks though!

Comment: The `plugin.yml` have to be in the source folder to be copied to the output folder and to include it in the JAR.

Comment: @howlger You're a true genius, that solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a **fat JAR** can be created **via the *Runnable JAR file***, but not via the *JAR file* export wizard.

So either

- create a **dummy main method** or
- use **Ant, Maven, Gradle** or something else

to create a fat JAR.

Make sure that you put everything in the source folder that you want to copy to the output folder and include in the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to IntelliJ Idea allowed me to export in this manner out of the box with default settings. If anyone knows how to get this function in Eclipse feel free to add it.

Edit: as per @howlger's comments I've found a solution where Eclipse works perfectly for my use case.